# If $A\in M_n(R)$ and $\det A$ is not a zero divisor, what can we say about its entries?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am working on this proof and think I have a lemma that will get it for me. However I am not sure if this lemma is true and can not figure out how to prove it, if it is. Here goes

*Given some $A\in M_n(R)$, $R$ a commutative ring, if $\det A$ is not a zero divisor then none of its nonzero entries are zero divisors.*

I would also like to make this an if and only if statement. Possibly

*The $\det A$ is not a zero divisor if and only if $\det A\neq 0$ and none of its non zero entries are zero divisors.*

Any ideas on proving this lemma or rephrasing it to something more useful would be much appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, I think you should give up attempts in this direction. Determinants and zero divisors just don't work like this. Don't forget that for matrices over $\Bbb Z$ you can make almost anything into a zero divisor at will by reducing modulo a well chosen$~n$.

Answer (score 6):

A counterexample to the lemma is an upper triangular matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal and zero-divisors above the diagonal.